# three.js: when the vertices of dashed line out of screen,the line gap is flurring

Tags: three.js, screen, vertices

the length of this dashed line is 1000, with dashSize=0.2, both of the 2 vertices are out of screen, the line gap became ugly, see below:

[image]

The version is r85.
code:

```
_drawMaskLayer(changeMaterial=true) {
    if(this.lineMaskLayer.visible===false)return;

    //the length of "this.baseLine" is 1000
    this.lineMaskLayer.geometry=this.baseLine.geometry;
    this.lineMaskLayer.geometry.computeLineDistances();
    this.lineMaskLayer.geometry.lineDistancesNeedUpdate=true;
    if(changeMaterial) {
        this.lineMaskLayer.material = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial({
            color: this._properties.color,
            linewidth: this._properties.size,
            dashSize: 0.2 / this.cameraControl.getCurrentScale(),
            gapSize: 0.2 / this.cameraControl.getCurrentScale(),
            transparent: true,
            depthTest:false
        });
    }else{
        this.lineMaskLayer.material.dashSize=0.2 / this.cameraControl.getCurrentScale();
        this.lineMaskLayer.material.gapSize=0.2 / this.cameraControl.getCurrentScale();
        this.lineMaskLayer.material.needsUpdate=true;
    }
}
```

To support line width，I attempt to use tubebuffergeometry,and dashed shader material,with only 1 segment,all of the vertices are out of screen,still got this problem,here is the shader code:

```
 let vTubeDashedShader=[
'uniform vec3 color;',
'attribute vec3 center;',
'attribute float distance;',
'varying float vDistance;',
'varying vec3 vColor;',
'varying vec4 vPosition;',
'void main(){',
'   vec4 mvPosition=modelViewMatrix*vec4(position,1.0);',
'   gl_Position=projectionMatrix*mvPosition;',
'   gl_PointSize=1.0;',
'   vColor=color;',
'   vec3 test=vec3(center);',
'   vDistance=distance;',
'   ',
'}'
].join('\n');

let fTubeDashedShader=[
'uniform float dashSize;',
'varying float vDistance;',
'varying vec3 vColor;',
'varying vec4 vPosition;',
'void main(){',
'   float dev=floor(vDistance/dashSize);',
'   if(mod(dev,2.0)<0.01){',
'      discard;',
'   }',
'   gl_FragColor=vec4(vColor,1.0);',
'}'
].join('\n');
```

And the code to draw dashed tube:

```
  initGeometry(){
    this.geometry=new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry(this.curve,this.segments,this.size/2,this.radialSegments,false);
    let vertices=(()=>{
        let ss=this.segments+1;
        let ws=this.radialSegments+1;
        let temp=new Float32Array(ss*ws*3);
        for(let i=0;i<ss;i++){
            let t=i/(ss);
            let x=this.curve.getPoint(t).x;
            let y=this.curve.getPoint(t).y;
            let z=this.curve.getPoint(t).z;
            for(let j=0;j<ws;j++) {
                temp[(i*ws+j)*3] = x;
                temp[(i*ws+j)*3+ 1] =y;
                temp[(i*ws+j)*3+ 2] = z;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    })();
    let distances=(()=>{
        let ss=this.segments+1;
        let ws=this.radialSegments+1;
        let temp=new Float32Array(ss*ws);
        for(let i=0;i<ss;i++){
            if(i===0){
                for(let j=0;j<ws;j++){
                    temp[i*ws+j]=0;
                }
            }else {
                let dx = vertices[i*ws * 3] - vertices[(i - 1)*ws * 3];
                let dy = vertices[i*ws * 3 + 1] - vertices[(i - 1)*ws * 3 + 1];
                let dz = vertices[i*ws * 3 + 2] - vertices[(i - 1)*ws * 3 + 2];
                let len = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
                for(let j=0;j<ws;j++){
                    temp[i*ws+j]=temp[(i-1)*ws] + len;
                }
            }
        }
        return temp;
    })();
    this.geometry.addAttribute('center',new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices,3,false).setDynamic(false));
    this.geometry.addAttribute('distance',new THREE.BufferAttribute(distances,1,false).setDynamic(false));
}
initBody(){
    this.initGeometry();
    this.material=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:this.color});
    this.maskMaterial=new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: {
            color: {value: this.color},
            dashSize: {value: this.dashSize}
        },
        vertexShader: vTubeDashedShader,
        fragmentShader: fTubeDashedShader,
        depthTest:false,
        transparent:true
    });
    this.body=new THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(this.geometry,[this.material,this.maskMaterial]);
    this.body.children.forEach((c)=>{c.raycast=()=>{};});
}
```

It happens only if the vertices of this line are out of screen.if scale the camera to ensure all of the vertices are in the screen,it looks nice again.And I don't wanna increase the vertices or segments to solve this problem，what should I do?

Comment: Please display your code. You have to display some efforts.

Comment: Please edit to include Three.js revision number (run `THREE.REVISION` in console)

Comment: seems like a precision issue,if I increase the number of vertices(line) or segments(tube),it would be better,but I still cannot figure out what exactly the problem is, :(